# How to properly access a char element of a 2D array of strings for comparison using C?

Tags: c, arrays

I created an array of strings like this:

```
char header[4][100];
```

I am then trying to access the first char of the 3rd element in the string array and compare it.

I tried:

```
strcmp(header[2][0], "/");
```

Gives me an error of :

*comparison between pointer and integer*

and also:

```
const char* tempheader2 = header[2];
const char* firstCharTempHeader = tempheader2[0];
strcmp(firstCharTempHeader , "/");
```

Gives errors of :

*comparison between pointer and integer*

*initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast*

I feel like i am missing something fundamental here...

If this is a duplicate, please mark it. I cant find anything but i might not be searching the right thing

Comment: You should be allocating memory through malloc for an array of that size

Comment: @sjdm - Not really.  It depends on the stack size which is likely much larger than that array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`header[2][0]` is a single `char`, not a `char *` like `strcmp` expects.

To compare single characters, just use the regular `==` operator and single quotes:

```
if(header[2][0] == '/')
```

Comment: I tried doing this :   if(header[2][0] != "/")     and got the error: error: comparison between pointer and integer

Comment: @JoeG Again, you're comparing a single `char`, `header[2][0]` (which is a numeric value) with the *pointer to a null terminated string* (namely, `"/"`). **Use single quotes**.

Comment: @JoeG Notice the code difference between `"` and `'`.

Comment: Don't worry, there are a hundred other subtle issues just like this just waiting to provide hours of enjoyment -- always try and understand what the compiler is telling your with its output.